# Is there a way I can know what files are affected by a CSS rule using Sublime Text 2?

Tags: html, css, sublimetext2

As above, I want to be able to find all files in a project which are affected by a css rule.
For example, I type "#header .container li" and I got all the files where that rule is applied.

Just to be more clear, let's say I have a project with these html files:

```
File 1:
---------------------
<html>
 <div id="header">
    <div class="container">
      <ul>
         <li>Something</li>
         <li>Something</li>
       </ul>
    </div>
  </div> 
</html>
---------------------

File 2:
---------------------
<html>
 <div id="header2">
    <div class="container">
      <ul>
         <li>Something</li>
         <li>Something</li>
       </ul>
    </div>
  </div> 
</html>
---------------------

File 3:
---------------------
<html>
 <div id="header">
    <div class="container">
      <ul>
         <li class="nomatter">Something</li>
         <li>Something</li>
       </ul>
    </div>
  </div> 
</html>
---------------------
```

If I type "#header .container li" (CSS rule) I expect to get file 1 and file 3 since them are affected by the css rule I typed.

Comment: you can search a project ctrl + shift + f

Comment: that has absolutely nothing to do with html or css

Comment: @kennypu That's not what I wanted to do.

Comment: @SvenBieder Sorry my bad. Anyway, I edited my question just to be more clear.

Comment: The only thing what could provide that functionality is an IDE. But I'm not sure if there is one that does that. I can say for sure that Visual Studio as well as Dreamweaver can't do that.

Comment: @SvenBieder yeah it has nothing to do with html/css, but I think that's the only way to find affected files between multiple files natively. If it's just one file, you can search for selectors using ctrl+;, but not for a whole project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the plugin/package [Element Finder](https://github.com/keeganstreet/sublime-elfinder) (nodejs is required).

Copied from [an introduction post](http://keegan.st/2012/09/01/introducing-element-finder-for-sublime-text-2/) of its author:

> Element Finder is a tool for web developers to find which HTML files
>   contain elements matching a specific CSS selector. You might be new on
>   a project, returning to a project that you haven’t worked on for a
>   while, or maybe a CSS selector is just unclear and you’re not sure
>   exactly which pages it will effect. Just copy a CSS selector into
>   Element Finder and you will quickly see all of the HTML elements in
>   your project which match that selector. For example if you search for
>   `div.main`, it will show you all the DIV elements with a classname of
>   `main`.

Comment: Thanks! This is a good approach. It seems like what i'm searching for.

Answer (score 0):

For users on an editor without support for the Element Finder plugin, you can use the same core functionality as a command-line interface with the [*element-finder* npm module](https://github.com/keeganstreet/element-finder) (by the same author).

```
npm install -g element-finder

elfinder -s ".layout-fluid #sidebar" -i ".tmp, dist" -x "html, php"
```

- -s is CSS selector
- -i is ignored folders
- -x is file extensions to search